# Swift 2: Update TableView from Separate Tab Bar Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog, tableview

I am working with Swift 2.0 using XCode 7.3.

I currently have 2-Navigation-View-Controllers(NAV1 & NAV2) . Each of which that has their own separate Table-View-Controllers(TAB1 & TAB2) with corresponding Tables (TABLE1 & TABLE2).

TABLE1 has a separate child tables (TABLE1A...TABLE1Z) based on data.

The second table (TABLE2) has a way of changing data shared by table1 and its child tables (TABLE1 & TABLE1A...TABLE1Z) via a shared, singleton class. The 2-Navigation-View-Controllers(NAV1 & NAV2) are each Modals of a Tab-Bar-Controller (TAB_MAIN). The singelton class is accessible through any Controller and is a means of data-sharing.

```
TAB_MAIN

-NAV1

--TABLE1 (SINGLETON)

----TABLE1A (SINGELTON)

----... [potential for multiple sub-modals/tables](SINGLETON)

----TABLE1Z (SINGLETON)

-NAV2

--TABLE2 (SINGLETON)
```

What I would like is the following:

1. Changes to the Singleton data made in TABLE2, to update the data in TABLE1 and all its child modals immediately. 
   Note: Currently this is working by updating the data in the singleton class through function calls; i.e. objectClass.changeData()
2. Once the data is updated, via selection of a specific row in TABLE2, I would like to :
   (a) change the currently selected tab to the first tab-view-controller
     NAV1. Note this currently works via: 
     tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
   (b) Update the displayed data in the table(s) for all the tables attached to the parent nav-controller for the first tab (NAV1).
   (c) Unwind to the first tableView of the first tab (NAV1).

Currently what happens is, changes in NAV2->TABLE2 update the data and change the currently selected tab to whatever `tableView` NAV1 was left at, without changing the data.

Only by going to the parent (NAV1->TABLE1) of all sub-tables (i.e. TABLE1A...TABLE1Z, TABLE1AA, etc) does the data get reset and then by selecting the `tableView`s and drilling down does the data display in the child tables get properly updated.

I would like to 'unwind' to the top-most `tableView` of the first NAV1 controller from within the second NAV2 controller, or, failing that, update the information automatically on switching from NAV2->TABLE2 to any currently drilled-down NAV1->TABLEX.

Comment: improved formating

Answer (score 0):

Try use observer in `NSNotifcationCenter` in your `NAV2-Table2`. Add the observer in viewDidLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Table2ViewController.updateTable(_:)), name:"NotificationUpdateTable2", object: nil)
```

then call to update using `postNotificationName` after perform update in another view controller. this will reflect changes in table2

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationUpdateTable2", object: objectData)
```

remember to put comments to easier track changes since the observer can be triggered anywhere

Comment: it should work. you can refer detail here https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/